# Ionic 3 Error: "File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it." in ionic cordova build/prepare android

Tags: android, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to do an `ionic cordova build android` command in my Ionic 3 project and I came across an error for `File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.`

Here is the trace in my console:

```
> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.
   Searched Location:
  C:\Users\Bryan\Desktop\iSpace\iSpaceProject\platforms\android\app\src\nullnull\debug\google-services.json
  C:\Users\Bryan\Desktop\iSpace\iSpaceProject\platforms\android\app\src\debug\nullnull\google-services.json
  C:\Users\Bryan\Desktop\iSpace\iSpaceProject\platforms\android\app\src\nullnull\google-services.json
  C:\Users\Bryan\Desktop\iSpace\iSpaceProject\platforms\android\app\src\debug\google-services.json
  C:\Users\Bryan\Desktop\iSpace\iSpaceProject\platforms\android\app\src\nullnullDebug\google-services.json
  C:\Users\Bryan\Desktop\iSpace\iSpaceProject\platforms\android\app\google-services.json
```

Many answers I found online were to download the `google-services.json` file and put it in my platform/android/app folder. However, as my firebase application is a **Web Application**, I can't download the `google-services.json` file from there. All I can do is to copy the firebase config over to my html page.

When I tried to search my file directory, I couldn't find any `google-service.json` related files as well.

Please help me with this! My aim is to be able to **run the application** on the **android studio's emulator**.

Note that my firebase application is a **Web Application** and cannot download the `google-service.json` file directly from the firebase console.

Comment: How is it a web application and you are doing cordova build android, which will create an apk

Comment: My ionic application is a web application so I created the firebase app as a web app. I did the same thing for my ionic 4 project and it could build without any issues.

Comment: Either way, when I went ahead to do an ionic cordova prepare android, it will still go through the build and cause the error.

Answer (score 1):

In the Firebase Console, under your project's [Project Settings](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/general/) you will find the configuration for your application.

As your project is currently configured as a web application, you will need to initialise your project to target other platforms (such as Android).

On the right-hand side of the page about halfway down, you will find an `Add app` button that will allow you to choose Android, configure it and then generate the `google-services.json` file.

1. [Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNWEj.png) - Open "Project Settings" and click "Add app" button
2. [Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6gKt.png) - Choose platform - Android, in this example
3. [Step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mx8hA.png) - Follow configuration wizard

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this!

I uninstalled the cordova-support-google-services by doing `cordova plugin remove cordova-support-google-services` and it managed to build. I tried to run it on **Android Studio** as well and it worked perfectly!